# Convert string representation of list to list with quote and double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

Although I referred many sources like [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)
 but I couldn't solve my problem below.

My list looked like below and I added this list to the dataframe as column, and saved the dataframe.

```
ls = [['abc'],['a"bcd"e', "ab'cde'"]]
df['list_col'] = ls
df.to_csv('path')
```

After, I opened the `df` dataframe, and I confirmed that the list changed to the string representation of list by the code below.

```
type(df.list_col[0]) # str
```

So I tried to make the string representation of my list to use the code below.

```
import ast
df.list_col = [ast.literal_eval(ls) for ls in df.list_col]
# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Is there any solution I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the `converters` parameter of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) when reading the file in.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# test dataframe
ls = [['abc'],['a"bcd"e', "ab'cde'"]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ls})

# save to csv
df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False)

# read file in with converters
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', converters={'test': literal_eval})

print(type(df2.iloc[0, 0]))
[out]: list
```

Comment: Oh this code worked for me!! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
>>> ls = [['abc'],['a"bcd"e', "ab'cde'"]]
>>> l = [i for a in ls for i in a]
['abc','a"bcd"e', "ab'cde'"]
```

Comment: Actually, what I intended was `[['abc'],['a"bcd"e', "ab'cde'"]]`, the original list, but thank you for your help! :)